# I ran a project I found online but I cannot input any more lines after the while construct statements

Tags: python, while-loop

This is the source code below. I wanted to write some print statements to see what the values were for certain variables but I cannot type anything else after I finished the while construct

```
from datetime import datetime   
from playsound import playsound
alarm_time = input("Enter the time of alarm to be set:HH:MM:SS\n")
alarm_hour=alarm_time[0:2]
alarm_minute=alarm_time[3:5]
alarm_seconds=alarm_time[6:8]
alarm_period = alarm_time[9:11].upper()
print("Setting up alarm..")
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    current_hour = now.strftime("%I")
    current_minute = now.strftime("%M")
    current_seconds = now.strftime("%S")
    current_period = now.strftime("%p")
    if(alarm_period==current_period):
        if(alarm_hour==current_hour):
            if(alarm_minute==current_minute):
                if(alarm_seconds==current_seconds):
                    print("Wake Up!")
                    playsound('audio.mp3')
                    break
```

Ive tried limiting the while body statements to just:
current_hour = now.strftime("%I")
but I still cannot type anything after. I'm suspecting its because of the while header and I'm stuck in an infinite loop or something

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what do you think the code means, and what do you think should happen when it runs? In particular, where the code says `while True:`, what do you think that means? What do you think needs to happen, in order for the loop to exit?

Comment: the While statement is a loop construct that continuously executes. Usually, there is a conditional statement the follows the loop construct but instead its a Boolean value. This was automatically an infinite loop I see. I need to change the code.

Comment: Well, `True` is always going to be true... right? See where there is a `break` inside the loop? Do you understand what *that* means?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is an infinite loop, it repeat over and over and in every iteration it reads the current time `now = datetime.now()` and comparing it with the alarm time you inputted to check if they are the same and fire the alarm, or they are not same and repeat the loop

this line reads the time:

```
alarm_time = input("Enter the time of alarm to be set:HH:MM:SS\n")
```

the time is expected to be in format `HH:MM:SS AM`
for example `05:35:14 PM`

since you read the input once and before the while loop, you can't input anything after the loop starts and it will be executing until the time of alarm come and then play the sound

Comment: Wow, I see! I see what the programmer was doing now. I learned a lot from this and I will be sure to write this in my notes! Much appreciated!